# How to get a trusted Jar from maven repository

Tags: maven, security, pom.xml

How can I get a trusted JAR from this pom reference:

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bea.wlplatform/commonj-twm -->
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.bea.wlplatform</groupId>
   <artifactId>commonj-twm</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: You know that this dependency is more than 13 Years old ? What do you mean by "trusted jar" ?

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your answer but knowing its age doesn't help me much!
About trusted: since I can't get the jar from [link](mvnrepository.com) I could find it in [link](http://mogwai.sourceforge.net/repository/maven2/com/bea/wlplatform/commonj-twm/1.1/) but I'm not sure that's a trusted worthy for the security of my app

Comment: First the age is something which is to be considered (about thing using more uptodate)...in relationship to "Trusted" ...furthermore mvnrepository.com is not a usable repository. This dep is available in Central repository...

Comment: from [Central repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/bea/wlplatform/commonj-twm/1.1/) I could only download the POM file but not the jar :/

Comment: Than this jar does simply not exist...